# Define a Select via a control table, SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is a bit of a weird question, but that's what the customer wants :)

They want to control what is selected via a control table. Reason for that is, that they don't know how the columns will be called in the end.

So when someone wants to run the code, they check how the columns are named and write it down in this control table. There can be up to 4 columns.

So the control table looks like this

```
Level1      Level2      Level3 Level4
--------------------------------------
columnname1 columnname2 Null   Null
```

So the code should select this

```
SELECT 
     columnname1
     ,columnname2
FROM table
```

The null values in the control table should be ignored.

I've already tried to do define dynamic parameters and write the select with that, but this of course only works when all 4 columns are filled.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: so as i understand if any of columns is null you should not select it ? otherwise select ?

Comment: yes kinda, lets say I create 4 dynamic paramters [at]Level1, [at]Level2, [at]Level3 and [at]Level4 
And the Select would look like that 
Select [at]Level1, [at]Level2, [at]Level3 , [at]Level4 from table
This would resolve in SELECT columnname1, columname2, Null, Null from table....

Comment: so, will you select only one row? because multiple rows can have any combination of nulls like 1st row has null in `Level1,Level2` but the second has null in `Level1` only, then how many column will you select?

Comment: @Johanna check my answer hope it will be helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a dynamic query as:

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);

select @SQLString = 'Select '+ CASE WHEN Level1 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE Level1 END +
                     + CASE WHEN Level2 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE + ' , ' + Level2  END +
                     + CASE WHEN Level3 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE + ' , '+ Level3  END +
                     + CASE WHEN Level4 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE + ' , ' +Level4  END 
                     + ' FROM controltbl '
FROM controltbl

--SELECT @SQLString
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution. Select the values into a in-memory table and then select the columns. This isn't that flexible as it requires some manual rework as you progress.

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
    Column1 varchar(50),
    Column2 varchar(50),
    Column3 varchar(50),
    Column4 varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @TempTable
    SELECT Level1, Level2, Level3, Level4
    FROM Table

IF EXISTS (SELECT Column1 FROM @TempTable WHERE Column4 = NULL)
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT Column1 FROM @TempTable WHERE Column3 = NULL)
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT Column1 FROM @TempTable WHERE Column2 = NULL)
        BEGIN
            SELECT Column1 FROM @TempTable
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM @TempTable
        END
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM @TempTable
    END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4 FROM @TempTable
END
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f1a3/1)

```
SELECT Level1, Level2, Level3 , Level4 
from table
WHERE Level1 IS NOT NULL AND Level2 IS NOT NULL AND Level3 IS NOT NULL AND Level4 IS NOT NULL
```